# Simple Python asynchronous server?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous

I'm working on a project where I now need the use of an async server. I was looking around at various Python libraries but there's little consensus on them. It seems Tornado is the most popular, but it's not Windows friendly from what I can see, and I'm going to be running the server on Windows.

I don't particularly need much for my server. A front-end is going to issue requests to the server. The server calls an API and sends back the information to the user. It does a bit of handling to ensure users aren't spamming the system as well as handling errors from the API.

If anyone could guide me towards a library that would work on Windows and be simplistic, that would be great. If they can point me to some tutorials/examples to assist in learning it, that would greatly help. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the async requirement? Do you expect to need thousands of simultaneous requests being served?

Comment: If you have some time. start developing one using `asyncio`

Comment: @Amber I would say I don't expect thousands of simultaneous requests, perhaps dozens or hundreds, but I can't be sure how long calls are going to be. The front end has to block on the calls, so I'd rather not have them keep sending calls in hopes one will yield a result. The middle server has to call to an API I'm not in charge of and can thus make no guarantees on all of it. I'd rather avoid blocking calls as a whole for this project.

Answer (score 0):

For the points you have mentioned, [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is the most apt python library. It has a light-weight core, is modular, has [extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) for all kinds of possible use-cases ranging from [database interaction](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) to [Admin Panels](http://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/), and it is up to the task for handling async requests.